# Which way would be more "Pythonic" for this exercise?

Tags: python

I have an assignment here:

> Given an array of ints, return the number of 9's in the array.

```
array_count9([1, 2, 9]) → 1
array_count9([1, 9, 9]) → 2
array_count9([1, 9, 9, 3, 9]) → 3
```

I have 2 ideas for this, one is:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    count = 0
    list1 = [x for x in nums if x==9]
    return len(list1)
```

and the other:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    count = 0
    for n in nums:
        if n==9:
            count +=1
    return count
```

But I wonder which way would be more Pythonic, in terms of performance, clarity,... ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

The most Pythonic way would be to use a built-in function, [`count`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) in this case. Try this:

```
def array_count9(nums):
  return nums.count(9)
```

Comment: @TruongTroll if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;)